# how to bind xml file to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i have Xml file..i want to bind this xml data into gridview..

my file:

```
<ExtPageList>
  <version>E36M3P6</version>
  <resultCode>0</resultCode>
  <resultStr>Success</resultStr>
  <objects>
    <ProcessStatus process="monitor">
      <id>6062</id>
      <condition>running</condition>
      <runLevel>7</runLevel>
      <state>sleeping</state>
      <starts>1</starts>
      <uptime>P3DT13H2M37S</uptime>
      <fds>21</fds>
    </ProcessStatus>
  </objects>
  <objects>
    <ProcessStatus process="manager">
      <id>6301</id>
      <condition>running</condition>
      <runLevel>7</runLevel>
      <state>sleeping</state>
      <starts>1</starts>
      <uptime>P3DT13H2M37S</uptime>
      <fds>57</fds>
    </ProcessStatus>
  </objects>
  <totalPages>1</totalPages>
  <currentPage>1</currentPage>
  <pageSize>19</pageSize>
</ExtPageList>
```

i want show this data as this formate with all data ..

Process  Id condition  state

Comment: hey dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3):

easiest way to do is using `ReadXml()` of a dataset

```
DataSet xmlData = new DataSet();
xmlData.ReadXml("D:\\books.xml");
gridControl1.DataSource = xmlData.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind xml file and display data of xml file in grid view . here is the code for that

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet authorsDataSet;
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("Authors.xml");
        authorsDataSet = new DataSet();
        //Read the contents of the XML file into the DataSet
        authorsDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);                    
        authorsGird.DataSource = authorsDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        authorsGird.DataBind();
    }

</script>
```

below is the html markup of grid view

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Reading XML Data into a DataSet object </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView id="authorsGird" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BackColor="blue" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="lastName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" 
                    DataField="firstName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </Columns>           
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried this one but i unable to get total records..please check my xml file data which i was posted and suggest me

Comment: <ExtPageList>
  <version>E36M3P6</version>
  <resultCode>0</resultCode>
  <resultStr>Success</resultStr>
  <objects>
    <ProcessStatus process="monitor">
      <id>6062</id>
      <condition>running</condition>
      <runLevel>7</runLevel>
      <state>sleeping</state>
      <starts>1</starts>
      <uptime>P3DT13H2M37S</uptime>
      <fds>21</fds>
    </ProcessStatus>
  </objects>
<totalPages>1</totalPages>
  <currentPage>1</currentPage>
  <pageSize>19</pageSize>
</ExtPageList>

Comment: mycode:     string filePath = Server.MapPath("myfile.xml");
            authorsDataSet = new DataSet();
            //Read the contents of the XML file into the DataSet
            authorsDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
            authorsGird.DataSource = authorsDataSet.Tables[0];
            authorsGird.DataBind();

Answer (score 2):

Check for the detail : [How To Read XML Data into a DataSet by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311566)

```
    string myXMLfile = @"C:\MySchema.xml";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // Create new FileStream with which to read the schema.
    System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream 
        (myXMLfile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    try
    {
        ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
        dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        //dataGrid1.DataMember = "Cust";
        dataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
    fsReadXml.Close();
    }
```

Comment: i tried this one but i unable to get total records..please check my xml file data which i was posted and suggest me

Answer (score 1):

```
      DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();//this dataset to read XML to datagrid
      ds1.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(”xmlData.xml”));
      gridview.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
      gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: i tried this one but with my xml file i unable to bind..and cont see multiple records

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers that have been posted should work;. I think that your issue is that the dataset sees your XML as two tables (not one).  Try binding the second table to your gridview, like this:

```
  gridview.DataSource = ds1.Tables[1].DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dataset ds_resp=new Dataset()
ds_resp.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("xmlfiles/PPForms.xml"));
gridview.DataSource = ds_resp;
gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.